# Companies House, extracting data from the response (rest API)

Tags: javascript, json, object, google-apps-script

I'm using Companies House API with a small google apps script. I want to retrieve the company numbers for a list of companies on a sheet.

I can't seem to be able to access the key/values of the response, can anyone help?

```
function findPayeeCHInfo() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var optionsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var payee = sheet.getRange("F6").getValue();
  var my_api_key = optionsheet.getRange('C2').getValue();

//Logger.log(my_api_key);

var headers = {

"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(my_api_key+":"),

}

var params = {
"method":"GET",
"headers":headers,
muteHttpExceptions: true,
};

var url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=" + payee;

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);

Logger.log(response);

}
```

my logger says:

> [20-08-02 16:14:00:624 BST] Logging output too large. Truncating output. {"kind":"search#companies","total_results":4163,"items_per_page":20,"start_index":0,"page_number":1,"items":[{"description":"01026167 - Incorporated on  4 October 1971","snippet":"BARCLAYS BANK INTERNATIONAL ","address_snippet":"1 Churchill Place, London, E14 5HP","matches":{"title":[1,8,10,13],"snippet":[1,8,10,13]},"address":{"postal_code":"E14 5HP","address_line_1":"Churchill Place","premises":"1","address_line_2":"London"},"kind":"searchresults#company","description_identifier":["incorporated-on"],"title":"BARCLAYS BANK PLC","company_type":"plc","links":{"self":"/company/01026167"},"company_number":"01026167","company_status":"active","date_of_creation":"1971-10-04"},{"description_identifier":["incorporated-on"],"address":{"country":"England","locality":"London","premises":"1","postal_code":"E14 5HP","address_line_1":"Churchill Place"},"kind":"searchresults#company","snippet":"BARCLAYS UK AND EUROPE ","address_snippet":"1 Churchill Place, London, England, E14 5HP","matches":{"snippet":[1,8],"title":[1,8,10,13]},"description":"09740322 - Incorporated on 19 August 2015","company_number":"09740322","date_of_creation":"2015-08-19","company_status":"active","company_type":"plc","links":{"self":"/company/09740322"},"title":"BARCLAYS BANK UK PLC"},{"title":"ZEDRA TRUST

i've used different methods of addressing object values and they're either not recognised, return a null value or return everything that you see above.

I wasn't even sure it's an object, so tried addressing it as an array, with zero success. According to the documentation, this is a subset of "items", but when i try to log `response.items.company_number` i get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_number' of undefined –

The resource representation is here:

https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/search-overview/CompanySearch-resource.html

any pointers will be gratefully received.

Comment: There isn't really a question here.

Comment: Welcome ! Indicate what is the output of the response and what exactly you want to get and you can't.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli - i want to extract the value of company_number

Comment: Hi @MariosKaramanis i've shown the log file above of response, i want to get the value of company_number. According to the documentation (link in question) this is a subset of "items", but when i try to log response.items.company_number i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_number' of undefined

Comment: @MK101 I posted my answer. Please accept if it suits your needs.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis ahhhhh ok an object that is composed of an array of other objects. thank you both. I voted but my rep is too low...

Comment: & @TheMaster  ahhhhh ok an object that is composed of an array of other objects. thank you both. I voted but my rep is too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) returns `HTTPResponse`
- [Get the `string` from `HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText()) and [parse the `string` to a `object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- `items` in the response is a array of objects. Access the object inside using `index` of the array and then use `company_name` key

```
var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);

var text = httpResponse.getContentText();

var object = JSON.parse(text);

var compName = object.items[0]['company_name'];

Logger.log(compName);
```